# Correct way to draw/edit a CVPixelBuffer in Swift in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, image, opencv, cvpixelbuffer

Is there a standard performant way to edit/draw on a CVImageBuffer/CVPixelBuffer in swift?

All the video editing demos I've found online overlay the drawing (rectangles or text) on the screen and don't directly edit the CVPixelBuffer.

*UPDATE* I tried using a CGContext but the saved video doesn't show the context drawing

```swift
private var adapter: AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor?

extension TrainViewController: CameraFeedManagerDelegate {
    
    func didOutput(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) {

        let time = CMTime(seconds: timestamp - _time, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(600))
        let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)

        guard let context = CGContext(data: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer),
                                  width: width,
                                  height: height,
                                  bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                  bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer),
                                  space: colorSpace,
                                  bitmapInfo: alphaInfo.rawValue)
        else {
          return nil
        }

        context.setFillColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
        context.fillEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        context.flush()

        adapter?.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: time)


    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0)` before creating the bitmap `CGContext` and `CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0)` after you have finished drawing to the context.

Without locking the pixel buffer, `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress()` returns NULL. This causes your `CGContext` to allocate new memory to draw into, which is subsequently discarded.

Also double check your colour space. It's easy to mix up your components.

e.g.

```
guard
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer) == kCVReturnSuccess,
    let context = CGContext(data: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer),
                            width: width,
                            height: height,
                            bitsPerComponent: 8,
                            bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer),
                            space: colorSpace,
                            bitmapInfo: alphaInfo.rawValue)
else {
    return nil
}

context.setFillColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
context.fillEllipse(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)

adapter?.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: time)
```

Comment: That worked, just needed the buffer lock.

Comment: I’m glad! But TBH I’m not sure those are your pixels to modify… oh well YOLO!

Comment: Definitely "fair use" and I created the CVPixelBuffer so ITS MY PRECIOUS lol. Thanks!